# scrapy - how to populate item with data from pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, scrapy

Suppose the following CrawlSpider:

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.loader import ItemLoader
from scrapy.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor
from tutorial.items import TestItem
from scrapy.http import HtmlResponse


class TestCrawlSpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = "test_crawl"
    allowed_domains = ["www.immobiliare.it"]
    start_urls = [
        "http://www.immobiliare.it/Roma/case_in_vendita-Roma.html?criterio=rilevanza",
        "http://www.immobiliare.it/Napoli/case_in_vendita-Napoli.html?criterio=rilevanza"
    ]

    rules = (
        Rule(LinkExtractor(allow=(), restrict_xpaths=('//a[@class="no-decoration button next_page_act"]',)), callback="parse_start_url", follow= True),
    )


    def parse_start_url(self, response):
        for selector in response.css('div.content'):
            l = ItemLoader(item=TestItem(), selector=selector)
            l.add_css('Price', '.price::text')
            l.add_value('City', '...')
            l.add_value('Longitude', '...')
            l.add_value('Latitude', '...')
            yield l.load_item()
```

and the corresponding items.py:

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.loader import ItemLoader
from scrapy.loader.processors import TakeFirst, MapCompose, Join

class TestItem(scrapy.Item):
    Price = scrapy.Field(
        output_processor=MapCompose(unicode.strip),
    )
    City = scrapy.Field(serializer=str)
    Latitude = scrapy.Field(serializer=str)
    Longitude = scrapy.Field(serializer=str)
```

For each start_url, I have corresponding geographic information ('City', 'Longitude', 'Latitude') stored in a pandas dataframe. For the above example the dataframe looks as follows:

```
     City Latitude Longitude
0    Roma    40.85     14.30
1  Napoli    41.53     12.30
```

How can I populate the items 'City', 'Longitude', 'Latitude' with the information stored in the dataframe?

Answer (score 3):

I would use `start_requests()` method to populate the [`meta`](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/request-response.html?highlight=meta#scrapy.http.Request.meta) information for every city, dumping the dataframe into a dictionary via [`.to_dict()`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_dict.html) to ease the lookups:

```
def start_requests(self):
    df = pd.DataFrame(...)

    # make a dictionary, City -> City info
    d = df.set_index('City').to_dict()

    pattern = re.compile(r"http://www.immobiliare.it/(\w+)/")
    for url in self.start_urls:
        city = pattern.search(url).group(1)
        yield scrapy.Request(url, meta={"info": d[city]})
```

Then, in the callback, get the info dictionary from the `response.meta`:

```
def parse_start_url(self, response):
    info = response.meta["info"]
    for selector in response.css('div.content'):
        l = ItemLoader(item=TestItem(), selector=selector)
        l.add_css('Price', '.price::text')
        l.add_value('City', info['City'])
        l.add_value('Longitude', info['Longitude'])
        l.add_value('Latitude', info['Latitude'])
        yield l.load_item()
```

Not tested.

Comment: Thank you for the suggested solution. It works well, however only for the start_url. When the next page is crawled, I get the error message `info = response.meta["info"]` and  `KeyError: 'info'`. Any idea how I could fix that?

Comment: @kanimbla ah yeah, that makes sense..`meta` is not being passed to the subsequent followed links..have not had this situation before, please see if this helps: https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/issues/704.

Comment: Thanks! I will check it asap. Since I write the crawled data to a MySQL database, I could alternatively add the information from the data frame using a separate routine. I just thought it would be easier to do everything in one go.

Comment: @kanimbla yeah, I was also thinking about that. Probably a more appropriate place for that would be a custom pipeline..fill out this information before inserting extracted items into the database. Thanks.

Comment: @kanimbla awesome, let me know if there is anything else you need help with in this topic. Thanks.